# Select root and exlude nodes from selection in XPath

Tags: xpath

Consider the following document:

```
<root>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
  <d></d>
  <e></e>
</root>
```

I would like to select `root` and all of its nodes excluding `e`. Pretty sure I need to use `not(name() = 'e')` or `not(self::e)`. For example `//root/*[not(name() = 'e']` but then I dont include `root`

The desired result should be:

```
<root>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
  <d></d>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Xpath alone is not capable of doing that. Xpath is not meant to transform, only to select. To select all nodes but not the `e` this XPath will do that:

```
//*[not(name() = 'e')]
```

To actually transform the result you could use this simple xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- The default copy template -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the e-element. And skip it by not outputting anything  -->
  <xsl:template match="e"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That does not include the Root node (also you are missing a parenthesis).

Comment: I edited my answer. I was using your example 'also' missing a parenthesis :-)